# Remove lines form txt file if specific string is found

Tags: windows, batch-file

I can not figure out how to remove a specific line with my batch script for the out put is:

```
type: MD2
status: granted
date: 2016/03/11

type: MD2
status: detached
date: 2016/03/11
```

if the status is detached then the hole block "type,date and status" should not be written / ignored in the output file

so what I am doing so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=10 tokens=1,5,9 delims= " %%a in ("Log.txt") do (
    set "date=%%a"
    set "type=%%b"
    set "status=%%c"
    echo %%c|find "more">nul && set "status=not granted"
    echo %%c|find "detached" >nul && set status=""
    echo type: !type!
    echo status: !status!
    echo date: !date!
    echo.
)>>Test.txt
pause
```

Example Log.txt:

```
2016/03/11 00:00:25:478 I LICENSESERV MD2 (Dassault Systemes V5) granted to client test (42FB1010C6B1ED82-0a292138.1)/172.1.1.1|d|d@EUROPE.S-1-5-21-1832937852-2116575123-337272265-547921.0A292138.1.GGL-42FB1010C6B1ED82|C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v170\AISOL\bin\winx64\ReaderHostU.exe 
2016/03/11 00:01:28:461 I LICENSESERV MD2 (Dassault Systemes V5) detached by timeout from client test (42FB1010C6B1ED82-0a292138.1)/10.41.33.56|d|d@EUROPE.S-1-5-21-1832937852-2116575123-337272265-547921.0A292138.1.GGL-42FB1010C6B1ED82|C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add some example lines from the input file `Log.txt`

Comment: @DavidPostill sry for this i maid a mistake and posted this question as a unregistered user.

Comment: @Mingebag Is every line stating with the date? And that is all one long line?

Comment: @Mingebag See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: @Mingebag I've edited the question, does the example `Log.txt` look correct?

Answer (score 1):

#### If status is `detached` then don't write the block "type, date and status"

This is easy to do using an [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) command.

Replace:

```
echo %%c|find "more">nul && set "status=not granted"
echo %%c|find "detached" >nul && set status=""
echo type: !type!
echo status: !status!
echo date: !date!
echo.
```

With:

```
if "!status!" NEQ "detached"  (
  echo type: !type!
  echo status: !status!
  echo date: !date!
  echo.
  )
```

Example input:

```
2016/03/11 00:00:25:478 I LICENSESERV MD2 (Dassault Systemes V5) granted to client test (42FB1010C6B1ED82-0a292138.1)/172.1.1.1|d|d@EUROPE.S-1-5-21-1832937852-2116575123-337272265-547921.0A292138.1.GGL-42FB1010C6B1ED82|C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v170\AISOL\bin\winx64\ReaderHostU.exe 
2016/03/11 00:01:28:461 I LICENSESERV MD2 (Dassault Systemes V5) detached by timeout from client test (42FB1010C6B1ED82-0a292138.1)/10.41.33.56|d|d@EUROPE.S-1-5-21-1832937852-2116575123-337272265-547921.0A292138.1.GGL-42FB1010C6B1ED82|C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v
```

Example output:

```
type: MD2
status: granted
date: 2016/03/11
```

---

#### What do I do if I also want to exclude status is `detached;` as well?

You can remove the `;` from `!status!`

Replace:

```
set "status=%%c"
```

With:

```
set status=%%c
set status=!status:;=!
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [variable edit/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) - Edit and replace the characters assigned to a string variable.

Comment: I am sry it works really good thanks allot for ur answer, quick side question if I want to have multiple words to search in the if sentence can I just do if "!status!" NEQ "detached" && NEQ "test" ?

Comment: @Mingebag 1/ I don't think you can do that. 2/ Are you referring to the test in "granted to client test"?

Comment: no not really I just want to filter out one more word since there is also "detached;" like that

Comment: @Mingebag Ah. Ok. It will be easier to remove the `;` from `!status!`. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: how about a second if ? is  that  not  easier

Comment: @Mingebag Not if it is just a `;` to remove. See updated answer.

Comment: @Mingebag Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). You will have to merge your accounts first.

Comment: WOW Thanks allot I will accept this answer asap . when this merging is done you rock man keep it going !